# VBA Listbox Filtro Automatico

Tags: vba, filtro, listbox

Podem me ajudar, estou tentando fazer com que o meu `listbox` carregue a  *planilha 3*, mas ele carrega apenas a primeira linha

```html
Sub Filtro()

Dim linha, linhalistbox As Integer
Dim valor_celula As String

linhalistbox = 0
linha = 1

Planilha3.Select

With Planilha3

    While .Cells(linha, 9).Value <> ""
    
    valor_celula = .Cells(linha, 5).Value
    If UCase(Left(valor_celula, Len(txt_referencia.Text))) = UCase(txt_referencia.Text) Then
    valor_celula = .Cells(linha, 6).Value
    If UCase(Left(valor_celula, Len(txt_tamanho.Text))) = UCase(txt_tamanho.Text) Then
    
    
Me.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "60;100;40;50;50;40;40;60;60"

    With ListBox1
    .AddItem
    .List(linhalistbox, 0) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 1)
    .List(linhalistbox, 1) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 2)
    .List(linhalistbox, 2) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 3)
    .List(linhalistbox, 3) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 4)
    .List(linhalistbox, 4) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 5)
    .List(linhalistbox, 5) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 6)
    .List(linhalistbox, 6) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 7)
    .List(linhalistbox, 7) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 8)
    .List(linhalistbox, 8) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 9)


End With

linhalistbox = linhalistbox + 1

End If
End If

linha = linha + 1

Wend

End With

End Sub

Private Sub txt_referencia_Change()
Call Filtro

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
Call Filtro
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Call Filtro

End Sub
```

Comment: pelo que vi falta um loop que faça que após o carregamento da primeira linha ele refaça a operação vc pode usar o for next ou do until

Answer (score 0):

Issac alterei disso;

```
.List(linhalistbox, 0) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 1)
.List(linhalistbox, 1) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 2)
.List(linhalistbox, 2) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 3)
.List(linhalistbox, 3) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 4)
.List(linhalistbox, 4) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 5)
.List(linhalistbox, 5) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 6)
.List(linhalistbox, 6) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 7)
.List(linhalistbox, 7) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 8)
.List(linhalistbox, 8) = Planilha3.Cells(linha, 9)
```

Para isso, veja se funciona.

```
.RowSource = "Planilha3!A1:H1"
```

Comment: Paulo, boa noite. Obrigado. mas não funcionou. Erro 380. Não foi possivel definir propriedade Rowsource. Valor de propriedade invalido. Sinceramente, eu tou desistindo já, uma coisa tão simples e não tou conseguindo concluir.

Comment: Não, não desista. Podemos conversar i se for possivel você me envia, autoeproject@gmail.com